# Alterações não surtem efeitos quando altero o Schema, usando mongodb e nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sempre que faço uma alteração no meu Schema tenho que reiniciar o meu servidor mongo ou o node para as alterações surtirem efeito.

Estou usando o nodemon, mas nem sempre atualiza, alguém já passou por isso?

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;

    var localizacao = new Schema({
        name : { type : String, trim : true },
        loc : {
            type : String,
            cordinates : [ String ]
        }
    });

    var funcionamento = new Schema({
        abertura : { type : String, default : '00:00:00' },
        fechamento : { type : String, default : '24:00:00' }
    });

    var agentes = new Schema({
        nome : { type : String, trim : true, require : true, index : { unique : true } },
        senha : { type : String, trim : true, require : true },
        foto : { type : String, trim : true },
        telefone : { type : String, trim : true, max : 20 },
        localizacao : localizacao,
        simulador : { type : Boolean, default : true },     
        funcionamento : funcionamento,
        limites : [],
        nivel : { type : Number, default : 3 },
        visivel : { type : Boolean, default : true }
    }, 
        { timestamps: { createdAt : 'created_at', updatedAt : 'updated_at' } }
    );

    return global.conexao.model('agentes', agentes);
}
```

Comment: Como que você está alterando seu Schema? Do jeito que está sua pergunta está muito aberta. Pode [edit] sua pergunta incluir mais detalhes como algum exemplo, trecho de código, como você criou seu Schema, etc?

Comment: pronto editei, o unique não esta respondendo estou conseguindo adicionar indice duplicado